# Xamarin.Forms cannot update Xamarin.Forms Package from version 2.3.4.270 to 2.4.0.282

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to update a project to the newest version of Xamarin Forms and I'm getting an error. The error is the following

Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.4.0.2' is not compatible with 'Xamarin.Forms 2.4.0.282 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0)'.

Although the error message is obvious, it's strange that the new Xamarin.Forms package needs an older version of Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.

So, I created a new project and I saw that the versions in the new project are:
Xamarin.Forms 2.4.0.282 and Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.4.0.2 (!)

That's odd. The new project contains the version 25.4.0.2 Xamarin.Android.Support.Design. The old project rejects the update because it contains that version of Xamarin.Android.Support.Design. Doesn't make much sense.

So, the question is Why, am I getting this error and why I cannot update to the new version of Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Have a look at this thread: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/77357/issues-with-xamarin-forms-2-3-2-127-released-today-sept-14

Comment: Not relevant to the current problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try update your android support libraries first and then update to the latest xamarin forms 2.4.0

Comment: There is no update for the Android support libraries! The support libraries are already at the latest version. If you read my message you can see that the update is asking for a previous version of the support libraries!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because Xamarin does not use latest versions of those android support libraries. You can see that when you install Xamarin.Forms package (Nuget-Manager: update only Xamarin.Forms), if it depends on newer versions of android support packages it will automatically update them.

So basically as long as Xamarin.Forms does not use latest android packages, they will always show  'update available' but when you update them, they're not compatible with Xamarin.Forms anymore.

**Edit:**

Sometimes it seems deleting packages and bin/obj folders is not enough.
If found this link with instructions for deleting nuget cache.

[Fixing Xamarin.Android build errors](https://smstuebe.de/2016/10/29/fix-android-app-compat/)

Comment: There is no update available for the support libraries. I have the latest version of the support libraries.

Comment: try deleting all support packages and xamarin.forms package, then just install latest Xamarin.Forms and it automatically adds the support files needed. (I recommend deleting your package-folder before adding again)

Comment: Do you have pre-releases enabled? If yes: try disable pre-release packages and try again

Comment: No, I don't have pre release enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the useful link. It's not really related to the problem. The problem is updating the packages not building after update. I solve the problem. Delete all the previous packages is one piece of the "puzzle". Restart VS after deleting some of the packages is the other piece. The update to xamarin forms 2.4 brings old versions of the packages (restart of VS is required after trying to update the support libraries)